# Why can't I get notifications on the questions I starred?

Tags: feature-request, notifications, bookmarks

I don't know what the reason of existence of the star feature is, but intuitively I star questions to express interest in it.

I think it would be nice to be able to get notifications on the questions I've starred (=expressed interest in, in my understanding of the feature).

Answer (score 1):

You will get notifications, but not that obtrusive, luckily. I have starred a dozen questions, and to get inbox notifications for every change on them isn't really appreciated by most of the users.

You can see the updates in your profile, under the [`favorites` tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=favorites). There will be a blue box with a number that will light up if there are updates.

Comment: Thanks. It's a little disappointing though, that visiting the favorites tab seems to immediately implicitly mark all the favorites updates as seen.